# Como funciona o cache de queries do Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel

Estou tentando fazer um cache da minha query, mas não sei como que recuperar os dados depois. Outra dúvida: quando número de linhas no banco aumentar, ele refaz automaticamente o cache da query, ou toda vez que eu entrar na página ele faz o cache de novo da query?

```php
$value = Cache::remember('users', 50, function()
{
    return DB::table('users')->with('ucomments')->get();
});
```

Comment: À comunidade Laravel: Estamos discutindo algo relevante com a tag de vocês aqui: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/310/como-tratar-tags-em-arvore. E ainda temos informações importantes para vocês aqui: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/300/diretrizes-para-criacao-de-tag-wikis. Aproveito para parabenizar todos pelo que estão fazendo aqui no SOpt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ao fazeres uso do método `remember`, a cachê criada só é mantida pelo número de minutos passados no parâmetro `$minutes`:

```php
$value = Cache::remember('users', $minutes, function()
{
    return DB::table('users')->with('ucomments')->get();
});
```

Como passaste `50`, ao fim de 50 minutos a cachê vai ser rescrita com o resultado de uma nova consulta à tabela `users`.

**Notas:**

- Enquanto o número de minutos indicado não passar, a consulta em cachê não será atualizada.
- No decorrer desse tempo a consulta em cachê não é atualizada, isso iria contra o objetivo de fazer cachê de algo.

---

## Recolher

Para recolher a chave `users` da cachê, podes usar:

```php
$value = Cache::get('users');
```

---

## Interessante:

- [Laravel - Documentação :: Cache](http://laravel.com/docs/cache) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>
- [Laravel cheat sheet](http://cheats.jesse-obrien.ca/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>

Comment: @hernandes É melhor evitar converter uma resposta de pt_PT para pt_BR. Para discutir este assunto, visite o nosso meta, especialmente esta pergunta: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/292/revisao-de-perguntas-ou-respostas-em-pt-pt-para-pt-br-ou-vice-versa-como-agir

Comment: Até então pensava que o foco principal fosse pt_BR(.UTF-8) não sou de nenhum forma contra abranger demais países de língua portuguesa em geral ( até porque o idioma é Português e não Brasileiro, rsrs). Porem devemos prezar pelo não uso de vícios de linguagem regionais.

Comment: Mas @hernandes, quais vícios? É uma boa discussão para o meta, você devia postar algo lá. Nesta resposta não vejo vícios, somente *diferenças regionais*. Não tem erro de gramática (sintaxe, ortografia, etc).

Comment: @bfavaretto, disse que é interessante não usarmos tais vícios, e não que a resposta em questão os continha, vou postar no Meta para não tirarmos o foco da pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Geralmente uso o método ***remember($min)*** na propiria query.

```
DB::table('users')->with('ucomments')->remember(10)->get();
```

O laravel vai armazenar um cache da sua query por 10 minutos.

Acho esse o método mais prático e fácil.

[Documentação Laravel cache de query](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#caching-queries)